# Jump weekends function? Django/python

Tags: python, dayofweek, weekday

I need to jump Saturday and Sunday automatically everyday so I can do a count in of certain element from a model. This is an example of the table I need to create:

```
Date ------- Order Holds

Today ------ 45 (wednesday)

09/09/16 --- 34 (Thursday)

10/09/16 --- 23 (Friday)

-----JUMP WEEKEND --- (and keep count in)

13/09/16 --- 56 (Monday)

14/09/16 --- 14 (Tuesday)
```

This is how I filter to count the number of holds for today, and I can keep getting them by adding 1 day:

This is my model(models.py):

```
class Data(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    ban = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

This is part of my logic (views.py)

```
today = datetime.today()
tomorrow = today + timedelta(days=1)
orders = Data.objects.filter(date=today)
ban = orders.filter(ban__contains="BAN").count()
```

As you can see in my views.py logic I can filter all the BAN status from today's date, after that I can count them with now issue. My problem is that I if I filter for tomorrow and tomorrow is Friday I need to jump Saturday and Sunday. In other words, apply that logic everyday by just jumping weekends.

Comment: Since the code shown only works for one day, `today`, I assume there is more code you did not show.  We can't help you if you don't show all the code, and clearly explain how it is failing you.

Comment: You didn't say what you're using, it looks like Django ORM, but we don't even know if it's a Django or a general Python question.

Comment: Sorry guys, yes I'm using django. let me upload more of the mode I have I will try to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the weekday number for a `datetime` by calling its [`weekday()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.weekday) method. Once you have that value you can test it to see if its one of the days you're interested in:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

DAYS_OF_INTEREST = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}  # Monday-Friday
DELTA_ONE_DAY = timedelta(days=1)
today = datetime.today()

day = today
for _ in range(14):  # next two weeks
    if day.weekday() in DAYS_OF_INTEREST:
        print(day.strftime(("%d/%m/%y --- %A")))
        #orders = Report.objects.filter(current_fcd_date=day)
        #hold = orders.filter(order_hold__contains="HOLD").count()
    day += DELTA_ONE_DAY
```

Output:

```
27/09/16 --- Tuesday
28/09/16 --- Wednesday
29/09/16 --- Thursday
30/09/16 --- Friday
03/10/16 --- Monday
04/10/16 --- Tuesday
05/10/16 --- Wednesday
06/10/16 --- Thursday
07/10/16 --- Friday
10/10/16 --- Monday
```

Comment: Martin, you rock !

Comment: What about applying that same logic and ignoring duplicates when count it?

Comment: You'll only have duplicates if the range of dates checked is over 7 consecutive days.

Comment: I found out that is not jumping the weekends, what if may be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the date.weekday() function. It is an instance method of the `date` and `datetime` classes in Python. It returns the day of the week as in integer, with Monday as 0 and Sunday as 6. So you would want to skip days with `date.weekday() >= 5`

See more here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html